# Why surface tension occurs

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy, water, fluid-statics, non-newtonian-fluids

I have this confusion of surface tension, in my books it is written that surface tension occurs due to cohesive forces acting on the particles which makes them to contract.  (If this is the case then gases should also have surface tension.)

My tutor told me that Surface Tension occurs because at the surface energy is more and less at depth so to have less energy it contracts.

So what exactly is the reason for surface tension to occur ?

Comment: Remember that  gas molecules have much more kinetic energy than molecules of a liquid

Comment: To obtain a good understanding of surface tension I would recommend reading CH15 of 'statistical physics part 1' of the legends 'Landau & Lifshitz'. You can probably find it online!

Comment: @Triatticus Careful there. At a given temperature, the molecules of a light gas (like hydrogen) have *less* kinetic enrgy than those of a heavy liquid (like mercury). To go down that road you would want to talk about the ratio of average kinetic energy to the average energy assocaited with the cohesive forces, or something similar.

Comment: What is lacking in other, easily accessible sites like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension)?

Comment: this has been asked several times here, and answered.Try a site search here and have a look at what's already been written about this.

Comment: @dmckee I'm aware of that distinction, what you mention is what I wanted the poster to think about but commenting from mobile is onerous at best.

Comment: @sammygerbil yes it does , thanks

Comment: @BioPhysicist Wikipedia does not really give a convincing explanation of the microscopic origin. It repeats the rather confusing explanations found in standard textbooks that the OP is already familiar with.